# position of an object after animation

Tags: jquery

How do i get the correct position of an object after animation for further work?

I tried:

```
$map.animate({top: t}, 200, alert($map.position().top+':'+t));
```

That gives me "old position:new position".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a callback function like this:

```
$('#test').animate({top: '+=200px'}, 200, function() {
    alert($(this).position().top);
});​
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/FEwjq/